# Docker Compose .env File Not Read

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a .env file I'm trying to use in a Docker Compose file to pass to the container to be used in the entrypoint script defined in the Dockerfile.

I have the following effective Dockerfile (spread out over two files, one override).  The `.env.dev` file is in the same directory as the docker compose files. The environment variable value is not getting passed to the container.  When I add "=${RUN_MIGRATIONS_ON_START}", the variable value is blank.  If I leave that off, then the variables aren't even set in the container.

Docker compose files:

Main docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build
      context: .
```

Override docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:

  web:
    environment:
      - RUN_MIGRATIONS_ON_START=${RUN_MIGRATIONS_ON_START}
      - WS_SCHEME=${WS_SCHEME}
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web:
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
```

**.env.dev**

```
RUN_MIGRATIONS_ON_START=FOO
WS_SCHEME=BAR
```

---

#### Why

```
environment:
  - X=${Y} # Y is a variable from the local shell environment, not from .env
```

Described in detail in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files)

> Your configuration options can contain environment variables. Compose
> uses the variable values from the shell environment in which
> docker-compose is run.

Comment: So essentially, leave off the `environment` section and just use the `.env` file and the `env_file` section, otherwise you're overriding what you set in `.env`.

Comment: Actually not described in detail in documentation, because it is unclear that `.env` file is not loaded when `--env-file` option was used.